# Ingest a big Geojson to Geomesa

Tags: geojson, geomesa

I have a geojson file that I want to ingest to geomesa.
As I understood from other posts, That I should create a converter to do so.

The file is as follow:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id_trip": 1547,
                "starttime": "2017-09-18 04:16:58UTC",
                "endtime": "2017-09-18 04:26:26UTC"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -73.651166,
                            45.544501
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651227,
                            45.544519
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.653826,
                            45.545258
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654753,
                            45.545521
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654917,
                            45.545565
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654615,
                            45.546086
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.65365,
                            45.545816
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.653426,
                            45.545753
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.653625,
                            45.545809
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.65365,
                            45.545816
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654615,
                            45.546086
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654917,
                            45.545565
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654753,
                            45.545521
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654167,
                            45.545354
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651227,
                            45.544519
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651166,
                            45.544501
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651457,
                            45.543993
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651702,
                            45.543567
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651561,
                            45.543526
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651316,
                            45.54394
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651044,
                            45.544401
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651011,
                            45.544456
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651166,
                            45.544501
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651227,
                            45.544519
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654278,
                            45.545386
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654621,
                            45.545483
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.654753,
                            45.545521
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Im having trouble to get the right json converter for these data, any idea on that pls?
The tutorial of geomesa does give some help regarding normal json but for geojson its ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMesa support type-inference for GeoJSON, as mentioned under the [ingest command documentation](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/cli/ingest.html#ingest). This will create a converter definition for you, which you can persist and tweak as needed. I would recommend using the [convert](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/cli/export.html#convert) command first (which also supports type-inference), and once you are satisfied with the output switch to the `ingest` command. If you are not using the CLI, then you can take the persisted converter and feature type definitions and use them in e.g. NiFi or your alternate ingest pipeline.

Comment: I really couldnt figure out how to do that, it asked me to give a converter

Comment: Thanks, However it does require me to specify a converter even though its written that "If a converter is not specified, GeoMesa will attempt to infer a converter definition based on the input files."

Comment: What version of GeoMesa are you using? GeoJson inference was added in 2.1.0.

Comment: I ran your file (after adding a closing `]}`) through the latest snapshot and it worked as expected. I posted the output on [github](https://gist.github.com/elahrvivaz/79c2f31079c311cdbad48e9c6473cf59)

Comment: Thanks Emilio, thats for the conversion to csv, how about ingestion? as it requires a converter to be used

Comment: The behavior should be the same for convert and ingest.

Comment: I understood now, I mistakenly tought that the geomesa version was 2.11 however it was just a tag, the reallity I had 2_11 1.3.2

Comment: Now Ive Installed geomesa accumulo 2.3.2 and now as you said it does not ask for a converter thank you a lot

Comment: But now I got this :
ERROR Unable to connect to Zookeeper instance within timeout period. Consider increasing the Zookeeper timeout by setting the system property 'instance.zookeeper.timeout' (default: 5000ms).

However Zookeper is running

Comment: I thnink I have to use Accumulo shell to set the timeout : config -s instance.zookeeper.timeout=2147483647
But the shell does not respond it nor prompt anything, it just satys like that

Comment: @pochi likely your connection to accumulo is not correct - I would suggest asking on the user list, gitter, or opening a new post so that we don't clutter the comments here.

Comment: Thanks Emilio, I figured it out, its strange but it was just accumulo version!